# How to persist data in a broadcast receiver

Tags: android

I have a simple broadcast receiver which receives some data which I would like to store for the application to use on next launch. It is just a few strings so simplicity is the goal. Normally I'd just write to to a file or sharedPreferences but not being an activity that seems incorrect.

Thoughts?

-- Henry

Comment: relevant - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3162715/save-data-in-broadcast-receiver

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Saving into SharedPreferences is perfectly fine. [You have a Context to access it from as it is passed into the BroadcastReceiver.](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getSharedPreferences%28java.lang.String,%20int%29)